# Why can't I pass my "for" index directly to a pthread_create call?

Tags: c, pthreads

```
#define THREADS_NUMBER 10
```

Given a function f:

```
void *f(void *arg){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("%i\n", *((int*) arg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}
```

I don't understand why writing this:

```
pthread_t threads[THREADS_NUMBER];
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++){
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, &i);
}
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

outputs this:

```
2 4 4 5 5 6 8 8 9 10
```

while writing this:

```
int t[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    t[i] = i;
pthread_t threads[THREADS_NUMBER];
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++){
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, &t[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

outputs this:

```
0 1 4 3 5 2 6 7 9 8
```

(In case you didn't notice the difference it's the argument passed to the thread function `f` in the `pthread_create` call.)

Comment: in first case you have only one `i` but in second case you have different `t[i]`. Also your first case has undefined behavior.

Comment: It's undefined when the thread functions runs relative to the thread that controls the thread creation, so in the first case, it's undefined what values the threads will see because `i` has probably changed by the time the thread function is running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try unrolling the loops. The two cases will become as below.

**first case:**

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, f, &i);
pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, f, &i);

…
pthread_create(&threads[9], NULL, f, &i);
```

**Second case:**

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, f, &t[0]);
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, f, &t[1]);
…
pthread_create(&threads[9], NULL, f, &t[9]);
```

If you have noticed, in first case you always pass `&i` to every thread, thus each thread will be pointing to same `i` and its latest content.

Answer (score 3):

Because here:

```
int i;
...
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, &i);
```

you pass a pointer to a memory address to your thread:

```
void *f(void *arg){
```

But when the thread is executed, the *main* thread already changes this value again!
So you have to pass a copy of this value, like you did with your array, or alternatively like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++){
    int *arg = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *arg = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, arg);
}
```

Remember to free the value in the thread function (`f`) when it is no longer needed — it's necessary to avoid a memory leak because there is no other reference to the allocated space.  Because of this, the solution using the array is probably better.